# How to freeze particle system?

Tags: unity, particles

I have set particle system of duration 5 seconds.

But, I wouldn't  like particle system to repete but to be frozen in fourth second forever.

How to do that?

Comment: You've tried using [the ParticleSystem.Pause method from the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Pause.html)? What trouble have you run into getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `Pause()` function of `ParticleSystem` class. Here is an example;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ParticleController : MonoBehaviour {

    public ParticleSystem particles;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //After 4 seconds, pause particles
        if(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > 4f) {
            particles.Pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Pause.html) for further information

Comment: Thanks, I need to add this script to partcle system which I would like to freeze ?

Comment: @Wildfire This script is written in a way that you can put it on anything and then assign the particle system you want to control with it to it by assigning it in the inspector. If you want this to automatically affect the particle system of the same game object, add this to the Start method: `particles = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>()`

Comment: As @Philip mentions, its for other gameobjects to control a specific particles. If you want tou control particles by itself, then use the code that Philipp posted above, and make the particles private

Comment: Thanks. What if I have multiple particle systems? How to add more lines to assign the particle system in inspector?

Comment: You can create a `public List<ParticleSystem> particleSystems` in `ParticleController` class. That will allow you to use inspector to drag `ParticleSystem` objects in to the `ParticleController`. When you enter a positive number other than 0 in the `size` attribute of the list, the slots will open for you to drag the objects.